# Determine probability of getting a desired outcome

Tags: probability

Say there are *n* distinct outcomes and you have ranked each one from 1..*n*, where the higher the rank the more desirable the outcome.

Now say that you are presented an ordered list of *k* such choices, where *k* < *n*. You are only told what the *current* outcome in the list is and what the *last* outcome in the list, where initially the current outcome is the first one. The rest of the outcomes - *current*..(*k*-1) - are unknown.

Now you are asked, "You can accept the *current* outcome" or discard it and see what the next one is. (Of course, if you discard the outcome you can't go back and choose it later. Once it's gone, it's gone.)

Is there a function to determine what the probability is for each possible outcome at each step?

A concrete example... there are 10 outcomes and you are given a list of 5 of them. You know that the first one is rank 3 the last one in the list is rank 7. It would be silly to accept outcome 3 (the first one) since you know in the worst case you can get rank 7. So you discard outcome 3 and now get to see the second outcome in the list, which has, say, rank 6. Again, you would be a fool to accept it since you have a rank 7 sitting there at the end. So onto the third item in the list... now here's where it gets interesting, this is a rank 8. Do you take it, knowing it's better than rank 7 waiting two spots away, or does it make more sense to discard rank 8 because of the likelihood that the fourth item could be ranked 9 or 10?

I'm hoping there's a standard formula for making this decision given *n*, *k*, the rank of the *k*th item, the current position in the list and the rank of that current item.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to specify some sort of utility function here.  How do I weigh the risk of dropping from 8 to 7 against the possibility of going from 8 to 9?  If, say, I have the option of choosing 5 or taking a $50-50$ bet on getting 4 or 6, which option do I take or do I simply work off expectation (so I'd see the options as equivalent).

Comment: @lulu: assume the options as equivalent - it would be equally bad to go from 5 to 4 as it would be equally good to go from 5 to 6.

Comment: So, it's straight expectation then?  At any given state of the world (when you have seen some outcomes and can calculate the available chances) just compute the expected value of going forward and compare that to what you have in hand.In your example:  there are two "better" choices out there and $4$ worse ones.  The probability that the fourth slot holds a $10$  or a $9$ iis $\frac 16$ (each) .  Since you'll take the $7$ in all other cases the expected value of drawing is $\frac 16\times 10+\frac 16\times 9 +\frac 46 \times 7=7.833$.  That's not as good as $8$, so don't draw.

Comment: You also need to specify how the list you're presented comes about. Is it presented by an adversary, or drawn randomly? If randomly, with which distribution? Can the same option appear more than once in the list?

Comment: To clarify assumptions:  I assumed the numbers $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ were permuted randomly (each permutation equally likely) and $k<n$ was likewise chosen uniformly at random (presumably between $3$ and $n-1$ or $n-2$).  But you should specify what was intended.

Comment: The list is permuted randomly, yes. Does knowing the *last* option available change anything?

Comment: Is your question related to “BANKER’S DEAL”? http://www.joytube.com/bankers-deal/

Answer (score 0):

Let's just use your example. And for convenience, let's just assume that the probabilities of all outcomes are equal. You are given a list of 5 outcomes, which now you know is [3, 6, 8, x, 7] where $x$ can be any other outcome.

You would want to calculate the expectation of the rank you get in the end if you don't accept rank 8. Suppose now you want to discard 8. Then the next one, $x$, can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, or 10, with equal probability (all $\frac16$). If it's 9 or 10, then you will accept it, because if you don't you're only left with 7. If it's not 9 or 10, then don't accept it. In this way your outcome will be $$\frac16 \times 10 + \frac16 \times 9 + \frac46 \times 7 = \frac{47}{6} < 8$$ So you should accept 8.

But this is a special example because there is only one unknown variable between the current outcome and the last outcome in the list. Computation will be more complicated if you have a more general example, say your list is [8, x, x, x, 7].